# What is the difference between require('electron') and require('electron').remote to get BrowserWindow?

Tags: electron

I'm new to electron. I'm reading the documentation and the [tutorial](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos).

According to the [documentation of BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window), to create a window :

```
// In the main process.
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

// Or use `remote` from the renderer process.
// const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote
...
```

What is the difference between `require('electron')` and `require('electron').remote`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Electron apps, you distinguish between the main process (usually setting up the main BrowserWindow) from the renderer processes (which execute inside a BrowserWindow).

Only the main process has access to GUI-related functionality, such as creating new windows. In order to have the renderer process have access to such functionality, the Electron developers built this shortcut that allows to access objects belonging to the main process.

From https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote:

> With the remote module, you can invoke methods of the main process object without explicitly sending inter-process messages, [..]